# Daily limit on queries amount in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, quota

[BigQueries quotas page](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy#queries) says there is a limit of 20000 queries per day.

- Is it possible to pay to lift this limit?
- Does [reserved capacity plan](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/pricing#reserved_cap) lift this limit on queries amount?

I was unable to find info page with clear information on this.

Thanks.
Maksim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query per day limits are mostly there to prevent people from abuse scenarios or for tiny queries that tax the system and aren't really a good fit for BigQuery. As long as you're using reasonably-sized queries, we're generally happy to increase this limit.

Reserved capacity does, in fact, lift this limit and others.

If you have a relationship with [cloud support](https://cloud.google.com/support/) that is usually the best way to proceed on quota issues.

Comment: Jordan, which Google API would you recommend (BQ, Datastore, SQL, ?) for us if we need to run a lot of small queries per day on table with lots of records? What is the typical use case for BigQuery? Background warehousing-like jobs?

Comment: If you have large tables that you're running SQL queries over, BigQuery is a great option. If you are doing point lookups, Datastore might be best. Likewise, if you're running more traditional database updates mixed with queries, Cloud SQL might be the best bet. It all depends on your data size & workload.

Comment: Our use case is: simple often SQL read queries over a simple table with lots of rows. We use BQ in GAppE Java application. Currently we have 2 issues: 1) limit of 20000 queries/day, 2) BQ has instability periods (at ~3-5 AM UTC time) - queries run too long failing the GAE limit of 1 min/request OR fail with "500 backendError"s OR return broken [QueryReponse](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/model/QueryResponse.html) object with no schema in it. When rerun succeeds if not in instability period

Comment: This answer is a bit dated now. The documentation has changed. It does not seem to say anything about a daily limit on queries: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy - does this mean there is no longer a limit?

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed the Google documentation and knew that GC BigQuery has a cap on quota on the number of DMLs (Insert, Update, Delete, Merge) per day per table and that is 1500.

But, it does not mean the number of rows but the number of statements. And, this quota limitation is because one statement like Update/Delete may affect millions of rows in BigQuery.